# How can I generate a String in a function in a viewmodel and return to a fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, observers

I want to generate a String in a function in my viewmodel and send it to the fragment associated to this viewmodel as a LiveData, how can I do it?

For example, my viewmodel:

```
class MaskViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var mask: MutableLiveData<String> = newQuestion()

    fun newQuestion(): MutableLiveData<String>{

        mask.value="255"
        return mask
    }
}
```

And the observer in my fragment:

```
maskviewModel.mask.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ result ->
            binding.textView3.text=result
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should not return a LiveData or replace the existing LiveData. You should only have a single LiveData instance so when the Fragment observes it, it will get all future changes.

```
class MaskViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val mask = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun newQuestion() {
        mask.value="255"
    }
}
```

But it is better encapsulation not to expose your LiveData as being mutable outside the class, so this is better:

```
class MaskViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _mask = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val mask: LiveData<String> get() = _mask

    fun newQuestion() {
        _mask.value="255"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be all set up to observe any changes to your `mask` variable within your fragment. To set a new String to it, simply call `mask.postValue(myString)` within your function. This will trigger your observer, which will receive the new value of `mask` as `result`.

Additionally, you are not assigning an instance of `MutableLiveData` to `mask`. Your `newQuestion()` never creates an instance of `MutableLiveData`, but rather tries to access it while it is still null.

Instantiate it this way: `val mask: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()`. Then you can call `.postValue()` on it. I've changed it to `val` because you can keep it as the same reference but still change the value within it. Keep it as `var` only if you wish to reassign it to a new `MutableLiveData` at some point, which is unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I call that method I get this error; ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.postValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference```

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tenfour04 mentions in his answer, your function should not return `LiveData`.

instead of returning the string from your `viewModel` , you could return it's id , and call the string from fragment.

**in the `ViewModel`**

```kotlin
private val _mask = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val mask: LiveData<Int> get() = _mask

fun newQuestion() {
        _mask.value = R.string.mask_value
    }
```

**in the `Fragment`**

```kotlin
maskviewModel.mask.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ id ->
            binding.textView3.text = requireContext().getString(id)
        }
```